# System.InvalidOperationException after updating EntityFrameworkCore from 2.1 to 2.2 for nullable property

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Since upgrading from `dotnetcore` and `EF` `2.1` to `2.2` I'm getting `System.InvalidOperationException`

I've enabled `options.EnableDetailedErrors(true);` which has given a slightly more helpful message showing the property name:

```
"An exception occurred while reading a database value for property
'Sale.AuthorId'. The expected type was 
'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' but the actual value was null."
```

My query is simply:

```
var test = await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync();
```

In the model, the property is defined as:

```
[ForeignKey("Author")]
public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
```

This previously worked in `2.1`. I've marked the property as optional (`int?`) so confused why this is being thrown.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer I would rather say the opposite. W/o any fluent configuration it works as expected. The exception in question is thrown if the relationship or the nullable FK property is fluently configured to be required.

Comment: @IvanStoev There isn't any fluent configuration on this field. Any ideas why the exception states the expected type was nullable, yet it's still failing on null?

Comment: There must be some non standard code or (or `[Required]` attribute on `AuthorId` or `Author`), because it doesn't reproduce in a clean project. You can try yourself in a clean project with just two classes `Author` and `Blog`.